# Nullptr Exception

Tags: android, kotlin

I was writing simple calc application in Android Studio.
At start I was testing some functionality.
and below is the code intermediately possible.

```
package com.example.calc

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    private val tv: TextView = findViewById(R.id.tv)

    fun onDigit(view: View){
       tv.append("1")
    }

}
```

It is not showing error but Rather it is saying launch successful on studio while on my local mobile
device I am unable to get the output or run the app where it is showing "App keeps Stopping"

And this is the Exception down there.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.calc, PID: 8213
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.calc/com.example.calc.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2876)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:169)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:684)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:842)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:809)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:633)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:259)
        at com.example.calc.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.kt:15)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1216)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

I am a beginner and Starting out I searched for google where I get nullptr exception but I couldn't
help myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `findViewById` on the class level where the application context isn't ready yet. You can call `findViewById` only after the context gets ready for you. For instance, in `onCreate` method.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit val tv: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        tv = findViewById(R.id.tv)
    }

    fun onDigit(view: View){
       tv.append("1")
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried two things at the same time and it fixed this error I removed jcenter() from gradle scripts and also implemented as above. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never use findViewById or bindings or even kotlin extension at the time of declaration it will always give you null pointer exception. The reason being the context is needed for the layout to bind with the code and it happens only after serContentView() before that the activity does not know from which layout it should get the views from, So, always use this things after letting the code know which xml to use